# Your comments and suggestions for my method of pulling page data from API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-core

What I want to do with the following codes is to meet the paged data I get from the API in my UI layer. Did I do anything missing or unnecessary here? Or do you have any advice?
Is there any extra code here in my `ApiService` class? Am I refilling my properties like `MyGridData`, `Parameters`, `MyPagination` for pagination in the UI controller or is this the way it should be? Can you help with this
API controller:

```
[HttpPost("GetData")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetDataAsync([FromQuery] GetDataPageRequestDto pageRequest)
{
    try
    {
        var predicate = DynamicExpressionParser.ParseLambda<MemberRole, bool>(ParsingConfig.Default, false, pageRequest.Predicate);

        var result = await _serviceManager.MemberRoles.GetDataAsync(predicate, pageRequest.Take, pageRequest.OrderBy);
        if (result == null)
        {
            return CreateActionResultInstance(CustomResponseDto<string>.Fail(Messages.GeneralMessages.NotFound, 404));
        }
        return CreateActionResultInstance(CustomResponseDto<IEnumerable<MemberRole>>.Success(result, 200));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return CreateActionResultInstance(CustomResponseDto<string>.Fail(ex.Message, 400));
    }
}
```

---

**UI Controller:**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index
        (
        int PageIndex = 1,
   string SearchText = "",
    int ActiveStatus = 1,
   string OrderBy = "MemberRoleID DESC"
        )
    {
        var MyAuth = await _AuthorityService.Get_MemberTypeAuthority(User.GetItemType());
        if (!MyAuth.isCanView)
        {
            return Redirect("/Auth/AccessDenied?isFancy=false&returnURL=Index");
        }

        string predicateString = string.Empty;

        bool isActiveBool = ActiveStatus == 1;
        if (ActiveStatus != 1)
        {
            predicateString += (string.IsNullOrEmpty(predicateString) ? "" : " && ") + $"isActive=={isActiveBool.ToString().ToLower()}";
        }

        PageRequestDto pageRequest = new()
        {
            PageIndex = PageIndex,
            Take = 40,
            OrderBy = OrderBy,
            Predicate = predicateString
        };

        //var memberRolesDto = await _apiServiceManager.MemberRoleApiServices.GetDataPaged(pageRequest);

        var apiService = _apiServiceFactory.Create<MemberRole, MemberRole_Index_Dto>();

        var memberRolesDto = await apiService.GetDataPaged(pageRequest);

        //revize et
        List<MemberRole> MyGridData = memberRolesDto.MyGridData;

        Pagination MyPG = memberRolesDto.MyPagination;

        Dictionary<string, object> Parameters = new()
        {
            { "PageIndex", PageIndex },
            { "SearchText", SearchText },
            { "OrderBy", OrderBy }
        };

        MemberRole_Index_Dto MYRESULT = new()
        {
            PageTitle = "Yönetim",
            SubPageTitle = "Kullanıcı Rolleri",
            MyGridData = MyGridData,
            Parameters = Parameters,
            MyPagination = MyPG,
        };

        return View(MYRESULT);
    }
```

---

**ApiService class:**

```
namespace Core.GenericModels
{
    

    public class ApiServices<T, K> 
            where T : class 
            where K : class
        {
            private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
            private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

        public ApiServices(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            var baseAddress = configuration.GetSection("HttpClientSettings:BaseAddress").Value;
            _httpClient = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAddress) };
        }

        public async Task<K> GetDataPaged(PageRequestDto pageRequest)
        {
            var url = $"api/{typeof(T).Name}/GetDataPaged";

            HttpResponseMessage response;

            try
            {
                response = await _httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(url, pageRequest);
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            }
            catch (HttpRequestException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Request URL: {url}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Request Body: {JsonConvert.SerializeObject(pageRequest)}");

                throw;
            }

            var jsonString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(jsonString);
            var dataObject = jsonObject["Data"];

            //Activator=> çalışma zamanında istenen tipteki nesnenin instance'ını 'parametresiz' almak için kullanılır. Parametre alınacaksa => Activator.CreateInstance(Type, object[]) yazılmalıdır.
            var indexDto = (K)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(K));
            
            indexDto.GetType().GetProperty("MyGridData").SetValue(indexDto, dataObject["MyGridData"].ToObject<List<T>>());
            
            indexDto.GetType().GetProperty("Parameters").SetValue(indexDto, new Dictionary<string, object>
            {
                { "PageIndex", pageRequest.PageIndex },
                { "OrderBy", pageRequest.OrderBy }
            });

            var pagination = new Pagination
            {
                PageIndex = dataObject["PageIndex"].ToObject<int>(),
                TotalPages = dataObject["TotalPages"].ToObject<int>(),
                pageSize = dataObject["pageSize"].ToObject<int>(),
                HasPreviousPage = dataObject["HasPreviousPage"].ToObject<bool>(),
                HasNextPage = dataObject["HasNextPage"].ToObject<bool>(),
                TotalRecords = dataObject["TotalRecords"].ToObject<int>()
            };

            indexDto.GetType().GetProperty("MyPagination").SetValue(indexDto, pagination);

            return indexDto;
        }
```

**ApiFactory pattern:**

```
 namespace Service.ServiceFactory
{
    public interface IApiServiceFactory
    {
        ApiServices<T, K> Create<T, K>() where T : class where K : class;
    }

    public class ApiServiceFactory : IApiServiceFactory
    {
        private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

        public ApiServiceFactory(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
        }
        
        public ApiServices<T, K> Create<T, K>() 
            where T : class 
            where K : class
        {
            return _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApiServices<T, K>>();
        }
    }
}
```